# Difference between standard and non-web version of ninject

Tags: ninject

I'm new to Dependency Injection concept. I want to learn it using ninject.

From ninject download page, there are 2 version of ninject :

1. .NET Framework
2. .NET Framework  for non web applications

**I have several questions :**

- What are the differences between those two?
- If I want to develop desktop application, can I use the standard version or I must use the "for non web applications" version ?
- What are the consequences if I use the "for non web applications" version of ninject on web application project such as ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None Web is for Client Profile applications. It has no InRequestScope